# Calculate values in multiple tables with records

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5.4

User can create tables and add records to it. When records added another values must be calculated. I tried to do that with jQuery but something is wrong and do not work. Maybe someone can help me and say how to do that.

Part from blade template (full template: https://pastebin.com/Mdq8fCnJ):

```
@foreach($tables as $table)
    @foreach($table->fuelAccountingRecords as $record)
        <tr>
            <td id="name">{{ $record->name }}</td>
            <td id="liters">{{ number_format($record->liters, 2, '.', '') }}</td>
            <td id="show_kilograms"></td>
            <td id="show_price"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="record_id"
                       value="{{ $record->id }}">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                        name="deleteRecord">Trinti
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

And jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var total_kilograms = $('#total_kilograms').val();
  $('#show_kilograms').text(total_kilograms);

  $('[data-table-id]').on('click', function () {
    $('#table-' + $(this).data('table-id')).append(
      '<tr class="child">' +
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" autocomplete="off" required autofocus></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="liters" autocomplete="off" required></td>' +
      '<td>-</td>' +
      '<td>-</td>' +
      '<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="saveRecord">Išsaugoti</button></td>' +
      '</tr>'
    );
  });
});
```

Another jQuery lines I am using to add rows to table where user can add records. I can not get a value from table and then ouput it or calculate. Help me to fix it.

[Empty fields must be filled with values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxogL.png)

Comment: `id` attribute values need to unique. Looks like you are passing the same value to several `<td>` elements inside the second `@foreach` iteration in the blade template. In your js you are targeting the exact `id` that you've set eg. `show_kilograms`. So if there are multiple `<td>` elements with an `id` value of `show_kilograms` this may be a problem.

Comment: Maybe you have any examples or can help me to do that? Because I am new in jQuery.